# How do I declare textFIELDShouldEndEditing?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield

I am having a problem keeping my keyboard active when I validate input and determine the user needs to make a change.  It was suggested I use textFieldShouldEndEditing and return "no" to accomplish this.

I declared that in my code with an NSLog at the very beginning and I never get there.  I did some research and found that it is declared in UITextField.h. I have a feeling I'm not getting that.  I tried to import UITextField.h and got an error.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and what I need to do to get textFieldShouldEndEditing called?  Some documentation I found indicated this method is called when a text field is asked to resign first responder.  I am doing that, but based on no NSLog entry I'm obviously not getting into the method.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you set up the delegate correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your class conforms to `UITextFieldDelegate` and you're setting it properly.

```
@interface YourClass: UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

And in your `.m`.

```
textfield.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Or connect it to the delegate in Interface Builder, whichever you'd like.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks much.  I got into the method now.  The keyboard still went away even though I returned "no" but that's another issue.  At least you got me to the method.  Thanks again.

Comment: Oops - apparently I needed to return NO instead of no.  Now it's working. Thanks again.